# How to download the monero blockchain testnet?

Tags: monerod, daemon

I want to download the entire monero blockchain on my local node. Where can I find the guide or documentation to download the entire blockchain? Will it run on the bitcore like zcash, litecoin etc...?

Answer (score 3):

To download the Monero testnet blockchain, you run monerod with the --testnet flag, ie `monerod --testnet`. The blockchain will start downloading. Note that you will need a current version of the Monero code: either master from github, or the release-v0.12 branch, as of now. The Monero software in 0.11.1.0 is not recent enough to use the current testnet chain.

I'm not sure what you mean by running on the bitcore, but it will run on most machines. If you can run the mainnet, you can run the testnet, and the mainnet and testnet chains are independent. Since Monero is not a Bitcoin descendent, it will handle differently from Zcash and Litecoin, but the principles should be similar.

Comment: Could you give me the link to the current version of monero? If any documentation on how to download the monero blockchain will be greatly helpful.

Comment: The repo is at https://github.com/monero-project/monero. I already said how to download the chain: run monerod (and add --testnet if you want the testnet chain). It is automatic once you run it, no further command needed.